# simple NetLogo setxy for list of coordinates

Tags: foreach, netlogo

For some reason I'm failing abominably at asking turtles to go to xy coordinates in a list. 
I've tried several approaches and though I can see why some of them are wrong I can't identify what's right.

(foreach [ 1 2 3 4] [-16 -16 -16 -16] [12 11 10 9]
  [ask turtle ?1 [setxy ?2  ?3 ]])

*following this, I could set a list of commands e.g. setxy for each but that seems a waste. Additionally I'd like to call the turtle by some variable rather than an item in a list.

Ideallty, I would like to set the list as a varaiable e.g. set mylist  [[0 1] [0 2]...]
But I'm not sure how to go about iterating through the items.

http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#foreach

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, first of all, your example code should work, *if* turtles 1, 2, 3 and 4, exist. Turtles in NetLogo are indexed from `0`, so I suspect you may be doing something like:

```
create-turtles 4
(foreach [1 2 3 4] [-16 -16 -16 -16] [12 11 10 9] [ask turtle ?1 [setxy ?2 ?3]])
```

And are getting something like:

```
ASK expected input to be an agent or agentset but got NOBODY instead.
```

...because your code is trying to `ask` a `turtle 4` that does not exist. Changing your first list to `[0 1 2 3]` would fix that.

Now is that the best way to do what you want to do? I don't have enough info to be sure, but I suspect you'd like something closer to:

```
clear-all
let coordinates [[-16 12] [-16 11] [-16 10] [-16 9]]
create-turtles length coordinates
(foreach (sort turtles) coordinates [
  ask ?1 [ setxy item 0 ?2 item 1 ?2 ]
])
```

You should be able to figure out how it works if you know that `sort turtles` turns your `turtles` agentset into a list and `item` allows you to get a specific item in a list.

**Edit:**

Doing `create-turtles length coordinates` instead of something like `create-turtles 4` will ensure that you have the same number of turtles as the number of coordinates you defined, but that's something that may or may not apply to your situation.

**Edit 2:**

An even simpler approach, that would only work if your turtles are not already created, would be:

```
clear-all
let coordinates [[-16 12] [-16 11] [-16 10] [-16 9]]
foreach coordinates [
  create-turtles 1 [ setxy item 0 ? item 1 ? ]
]
```

Comment: Very nice. That answered a few questions I had about netlogo e.g. indexing and some nice insight e.g. sort turtles.

Comment: Nice approach, but unfortunately the use of "foreach" seems to have changed in the meantime (I am using Netlogo 6.0.4 at the moment).
I tried 
">>> let coordinates [[1 3] [2 2] [ 3 1] [3 -1] [2 -2] [1 -3]]

>>>  foreach coordinates [
    [a b] -> create-turtles 1 [ setxy a b]
]"

instead, but it didn't work. Can anybody help me?

Comment: @Sayuri, you need `foreach coordinates [ xy -> create-turtles 1 [ setxy item 0 xy item 1 xy ] ]`.